# why when I find the best accuracy for logistic regression then it give me this error (AttributeError: split not found)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pandas, logistic-regression, gridsearchcv

after run this code I face the split not found error.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer



tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents=None,
                        lowercase=False,
                        preprocessor=None)

param_grid = [{'vect__ngram_range': [(1, 1)],
               'vect__stop_words': [stop_words, None],
               'vect__tokenizer': [tokenizer, tokenizer_porter],
               'vect__preprocessor': [None, preprocessor],
               'clf__penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
               'clf__C': [1.0, 10.0, 100.0]},
              {'vect__ngram_range': [(1,1)],
               'vect__stop_words': [stop_words, None],
               'vect__tokenizer': [tokenizer, tokenizer_porter],
               'vect__preprocessor': [None, preprocessor],
               'vect__use_idf':[False],
               'vect__norm':[None],
               'clf__penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
               'clf__C': [1.0, 10.0, 100.0]},
              ]

lr_tfidf = Pipeline([('vect', tfidf),
                     ('clf', LogisticRegression(random_state=0))])
#The parameters of the estimator used to apply these methods are optimized by cross-validated grid-search over a parameter grid
gs_lr_tfidf = GridSearchCV(lr_tfidf, param_grid,
                           scoring='accuracy',
                           cv=5,
                           verbose=1,
                           n_jobs=-1)
gs_lr_tfidf.fit(X_train, y_train)'''
```

AttributeError: split not found

Comment: This code works fine for me. The problem is likely with one of your tokenizing or preprocessing functions.

Comment: Yes it fine but when i run first time it work but after second time then it not work.